How to query a reverse foreign key multiple times in Django ORM
Assuming the following models:
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.PROTECT)


class Consignment(models.Model):
    cost = models.FloatField()


class Order(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    consignment = models.ForeignKey(Consignment, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

How to create a queryset of all 'consignments' of all instances of a specific 'stores' queryset like so:
target_stores = Store.objects.filter(name__startswith="One")
consignments = target_stores.consignments.all()


So when is a Consignment related to a store, if there is an Order that links to a Stock that links to such Store?

You query in reverse by spanning over multiple relations with the __ separator:
Consignment.objects.filter(order__stock__store__name__startswith='One')

I tried this solution but i got FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'order' into field. Choices are: cost, orders

@AhmedAshraf: that's because you specified a related_name='orders', so then it is orders__ instead of order__.
